# tomcat not reflecting java changes on server restart

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, eclipse-juno

I am running a maven project on tomcat in eclipse using m2e plugin. From past 2 days I am facing this problem. Tomcat is not reflecting the java changes done after restart. It was working fine few days back.

Only if I clean build the project via maven & restart the project, the changes are being reflected which consumes additional time. Sometimes I have to even delete the classes folder to get the changes reflected.

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is this under eclipse mars?

Comment: I saw a similar problem under eclipse Mars yesterday and was not quite clear on what happened

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I am unclear on what happened - I shutdown eclipse, performed a manual clean/package from the command-line, restarted eclipse, forced the server adapter to clean the deployed configuration and work directory and it resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue can happen if `Build automatically` flag is turned off.

Click on menu option `Project -> Build automatically` to enable it back.